What is a vector field on manifolds?
I am unsure about the definition of a vector field. I understand that a vector field is a special vector-valued function, namely, a vector-valued function which space of output vectors must have the same dimension as the space of the input points.
This is where it gets murky for me: If the space of input points is a manifold, then these input points are not necessarily vectors for which vector-addition and scalar-multiplication applies.
To illustrate, I imagine a 3d Euclidean space in which a 2d-curve is the manifold on which the vector-valued function is defined.
If I want to define a vector field with the manifold being the domain, then the output vectors of the vector field must be 2d. I guess the "vectors" of the field must "point" at a point on the manifold? Then, I could imagine that it is possible to define vector-addition and scalar-multiplication for them such that the output values of the vector field are vectors -- but this could not be typical Euclidean addition/multiplication, but something really intricate.
This understanding is what seems to be shown in the wikipedia image

Let's call this the "first understanding".
However, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Vector_fields_on_manifolds says

Given a differentiable manifold M, a vector field on M is an assignment of a tangent vector to each point in M.

Let us call this the second understanding, which sounds to me to contradict the first understanding.
Both, the output vectors of the first and the tangent vectors of the second understanding have a dimension of 2.
I think the same principles can be applied to a 1d manifold in 3d space.
What understanding is correct? Please explain as simple as possible.

Can you explicit what you see as a contradiction? Do you know the notion of the tangent space of a manifold?

@mathcounterexamples.net: I hope so. I seems the image on the wikipedia page "tangent space" is pretty explanatory. However, I am not sure what a tangent space would be if the manifold is 1d in a 3d space.

@mathcounterexamples.net: The questions is this: Is an output of the vector field (applied to a point in the input manifold) pointing to an element of the tangent space or to an element of the input manifold? The two "understandings" seem to be exclusive to me, because the elements of the tangent space are not necessarily elements of the input manifold and vice versa.

@Make42 "Understanding 2" tells you the answer. You can discard "understanding 1" pretty much entirely: Pretty much nothing you say in the first half of the question is true, and where you take these interpretations from is a mystery to me. For instance, "a vector-valued function which output vectors must have the same dimension as the input points" is nonsense on the nose: points have dimension 0. ...or the fact that it is completely irrelevant whether the input points are "vectors" in some sense or not.

There is a concise, correct answer to "what's a vector field of a manifold:" It's a (smooth) section of the tangent bundle $TM$, i.e. a section of the projection map $TM \to M$. In laypeople's terms, if you have submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then you can talk about the tangent space at each point $M$ (this is what Wiki illustrates), which is a real vector space of dimension that of the manifold, and then a vector field is a function that assigns to each $x \in M$ an element of this tangent space, in a way that varies smoothly with $x$ (whatever that means).

In any case, I think this question is a good demonstration of why you shouldn't rely on Wikipedia to learn mathematics. I highly recommend picking up any textbook on smooth manifolds (for instance Lee's) and reading about tangent spaces and vector fields there instead.

@BenSteffan: I got my "first understanding" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_function#Vector_field: "A vector field is a special case of a vector-valued function, whose domain's dimension has no relation to the dimension of its range; for example, the position vector of a space curve is defined only for smaller subset of the ambient space."

@BenSteffan: Also, I got the first understanding from the image, as I wrote. So, I it is a mystery to me, why this is a mystery to you :-D.

@BenSteffan: My understanding of "dimension" is the variability of the element of the thing which has the dimension. So a surface in has dimension 2, a line has dimension 1. Thus, the points have dimension 0 yes, but I think I said that the manifold has dimension 2, not the points of the manifold. A vector does not have a dimension either, but their vector space does. So the dimension of the input and the output spaces of a vector field have to be the same in my both the first and second understanding.

"I understand that a vector field is a special vector-valued function, namely, a vector-valued function which output vectors must have the same dimension as the input points." both contradicts the explicit wiki quote you gave and "I think I said that the manifold has dimension 2, not the points of the manifold."  As for the image, it's somewhat misleading, I agree, but also it accompanies the definition of vector field, which is rather incompatible with your interpretation.

@BenSteffan: I corrected the respective text; thanks for pointing out! Ok, so I accept that the second understanding is correct. I think my first understanding is a "smooth map" (reading Lee, chapter 2).

Best guesses after reading the question and comments: (i) There is confusion about dimension of a point. Mathematicians don't speak this way (physicists and engineers might); "vector spaces" and "manifolds" have dimensions, but individual vectors and points do not. (ii) "Dimension of a point" coincides with "dimension of a manifold" for open sets in Cartesian space. In this situation we can (correctly, but misleadingly) think of a "vector field" as a vector-valued function. (iii) There is confusion about "How can a tangent vector lie on a surface or curve?" (Answer: "It doesn't, sort of.")

You would be much better served by reading a textbook (differential geometry or differential topology) where the definition of a vector field is explained instead of reading Wikipedia or trying to guess.

@MoisheKohan: Any recommendations? I am an engineer, so I am not familiar with mathematical standard literature.

Given the fact that you probably do not know any general topology, your best option is the book by Guillemin and Pollack, "Differential Topology." They only consider manifolds embedded in some $\mathbb R^n$, but that should be enough for you at this point.

@MoisheKohan: Thank you for the book recommendation! I work in computer science. I usually know what I want to construct, but I often do not know what the right terminology is and I try to find out how to call those things in my head.
